# C-h i info behaves differently to the info program

Tags: emacs, info

On an Ubuntu 16.10 setup, running "info gcc" in shell will lead me to the correct info document (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6). However, in the C-h i version, 
a) I am not able to visit x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6 (error: user-error: Info file x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6 does not exist). Also, hitting 'm' and typing in gcc,expectedly perhaps, also doesn't work. Is there a problem with the emacs info installation, or .. how do I go about this?

Comment: What does comparing the result of `echo $INFOPATH` in console to `M-:(getenv "INFOPATH")` in Emacs show? Also, [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPath) might be of help.

Comment: returns nil, but Info-directory-list does contain /usr/share/info, where the problematic info document resides;